# (psycopg2.OperationalError) FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres"

Tags: python, postgresql, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I deployed a simple app that catch the ip_address, timestamp, latitude and longitude to Google App Engine by referring to this tutorial -> https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/using-cloud-sql-postgres

I did what the tutorial showed and was able to run `python main.py` locally on my machine. Below is the result(the actual result shows the value for latitude and longitude. This is for example)

```
Last 10 visits:
Time: 2017-03-13 07:19:13.330896 Addr: 127.0 Latitude: <some value> Longitude <some value>
Time: 2017-03-13 07:19:06.486184 Addr: 127.0 Latitude: <some value> Longitude <some value>
```

It saves this data into database that I created earlier by using `python create_tables.py` as instructed in the tutorial.

Then I deploy the app on Google App Engine but there is error saying

```
(psycopg2.OperationalError) FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

when I visit the link `https://<project_id>.appspot.com`(Note that actual link does have the project id, this is for example only)

[Additional Information]

In the tutorial, there is section for setting up local environment to test the app. I did like what in the tutorial by installing the copy of Cloud SQL Proxy in my local environment and below is the result.

```
Fang-Air:~ Fang$ ./cloud_sql_proxy -dir=/cloudsql &
[1] 81439
Fang-Air:~ Fang$ 2017/03/13 15:44:33 Using gcloud's active project: <project_id>
2017/03/13 15:44:43 Error listing instances in <project_id>: Get https://www.googleapis.com/sql/v1beta4/projects/<project_id>/instances?alt=json: Post https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token: net/http: TLS handshake timeout
2017/03/13 15:44:43 no Cloud SQL Instances found in these projects: [<project_id>]
```

I rechecked my project and there is an instance with postgres database in it but in this result it shows that no cloud sql instance found.

I wonder if this is related to the problem that I faced after deploying my application but as what I understand from the tutorial, this is just for local environment.

Regarding my problem, I wonder if anyone have suggestion or a way on how to troubleshoot this error.

My operating system and Postgresql version is

```
OS X El Capitan 10.11.6
psycopg2 2.6.2
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: While I'm not sure if it relates to the problem immediately at hand, do *not* use the `postgres` user for your webapp's normal production connections. Use a non-superuser you create with `CREATE USER` and grant just the rights needed, or database ownership.

Comment: Are you able to follow https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/using-cloud-sql-postgres#creating_an_instance_and_setting_the_password to set the password and connect to your instance with psql first? Also, please note the connection name is in the format of: project1:us-central1:instance1

Comment: @Tianzhou can you elaborate more on `setting the password and connect to your instance with psql first`? I thought by creating the instance with postgresql database and set the connection in `app.yaml` is the way to connect to the database. I also rechecked the format for the connection name and it is correct.

I did create the instance from the `console.cloud.google.com/sql/instances`, choose postgres, set instance id, set the password for `postgres` user and create the instance

Comment: @Fang, I mean are you able to follow this guide to connect using 'psql' first: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-admin-ip#connect

The error says password authentication failed for user "postgres"

So I suspect you don't set the right password in your app engine application when connecting to the postgres instance.

Comment: @Fang If you were able to find the solution to this question I ask that you post it as an answer for the rest of the community. If you are still experiencing this issue, I ask that you provide more information about how exactly you are connecting to your Cloud SQL instance (with provided code samples). If you are connecting from App Engine, make sure you have followed each step in the [Granting access to App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/using-cloud-sql-postgres#granting_access_to_gae_name_short) guide.

Comment: @Jordan sorry for late reply. I just redo back by following the tutorial from start. I did not really know what caused this problem but the second time I tried, there is no error. The problem is likely from when I created the database on the console. I created the database with the default name and password